# AWS S3 CP-- properties to limit the number of files to be copied?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

what is the aws s3 cp command properties/parameter to limit the number of files . our s3 bucket has 6K files. but we wanted to copy like 100 at a time . any way to limit the number of files ?

Comment: No, there is no such option. Can I ask why you are wanting to do this? Is there a problem with storage space or bandwidth? If you let us know more about your situation, we might be able to come up with an alternative approach.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @JohnRotenstein. 

yes, there are around 6K files on S3 bucket and we cannot copy all the files from S3 to our local with a single transfer, it has to be done batch by batch and i thought of doing 100 files at a time.

Comment: What is blocking you from copying all the files? Is it a storage limitation? Have you considered copying specific subdirectories? Please tell us more so that we can best help you.

Comment: Yes the size of the files is close to 350GB. I don’t think we can transfer that much data via single transfer job.

Comment: Sure you can. Things might go wrong if you have an unreliable network connection, but the size doesn't limit your ability to copy. I recommend using the `aws s3 sync` command because it can resume failed copy situations. It synchronizes destinations. This means that is only copies files that are new or changed since a previous `sync`. So, if something goes wrong, you just run it again. It is a little slow to start because it needs to compare all files between source and destination, so it runs quicker if you just do a subdirectory, but give it a try anyway!